# TypeScript ` vs ' vs "

Tags: typescript

What is the difference in the following three string assignments?

```
let a: string = `my text`;
let b: string = 'my text';
let c: string = "my text";
```

They all work perfectly fine. It it just a matter of personal taste which one to use or are there differences?

Comment: @JoeClay not exactly a duplicate since he also asks about single and double quoted strings (although I'm sure that was asked before too)

Comment: @Motti: Yeah, you're right - close but it's not quite a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not actually related to Typescript. Its part of Javascript.

```
let a: string = `my text`; ---> template literal
let b: string = 'my text'; ---> just a string
let c: string = "my text"; ---> just a string
```

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) were added in ES6 and they allow interpolation:

```
let name = 'Martin';
let greetings = `Hello ${name}, how are you?`; // result: Hello Martin, how are you?
```

Answer (score 4):

Back ticks are actually part of JavaScript ([template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) and they allow embedding expressions. Typescript allows you to use them even if you're using an older version of JavaScript by [transpiling](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2012/11/compiling-vs-transpiling/) it to string concatenation if you're targeting older JavaScript.

```
let user = "Socrates";
`Hi there ${user}` ; // Hi there Socrates
`Did you know your name is ${user.length} chars long?`;
```

As for the differences between double and single quotes, there is no difference, they allow you to avoid escaping the quote chars if only one type is used inside the string.

```
'I asked "how are you?"'; // clearer than "I asked \"how are you?\""
"Frankly my dear, I don't give a damn"; // vs don\'t
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a template string that was introduce in `es2015` , you can read more about the [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but the gist of it is that you can do variable substitution in the string

```
let nr = 0 
let a: string = `my text ${nr}`;
```

The other two are standard JavaScript string, you ca use either or, but it is recommended you stick to one.

Comment: I would argue that avoiding `\\` is more important than using consistent quotes.